# Evaluating subset of a list using in operator

Tags: python

I have following test code.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
c = a * 3
b = a
```

but `b in c` returns False. b is a sub sequence of c and the list c contains b. So why is it returning false?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK. It seems that in operator will work only for an object in a sequence. So it will not work for finding if a list is a sublist of another list. I found a way to evaluate that by using tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b in c
```

Does not work because b looks like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

and c looks like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

In other words, b is not an element of the sequence.  Instead, b is a subsequence.  If you were to construct c as follows:

```
c = [a, a, a]
```

Then c would look like:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
```

And "b in c" would return True.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had this code:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
c = [a] * 3
b = a
```

when you type `b in c` you would get `True`.

In this case

`c = [a] * 3`  (with [ ] around a)

would return:

`[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]`